# Stop Html Agility Pack from changing source code

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I wan't to change specific text in a bunch of HTML files and save the rest of their code unchanged. I figured out that I'll use Html Agility pack. So I wrote code like this:

```
        string Url = @"http://www.example.com";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36";
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
        doc.Save("a.html");
```

But the problem is that the source of the website saved differs from the original. Is there a way to prevent changing the source. Or maybe there's another way to be able to move through the DOM and change just specific things (like in chrome developer tools where you can save later as HTML, bu automatically).

----------- EDIT --------

For example it is seen on eBay. I can't post a link because it would be advertising but if you just try this code on any item offer you will see what's going on.

---------- EDIT2 --------

It seems that eBay is using iframes, and the HAP can't handle it. The  and  tags inside it are removed so probably that is the reason why saved website differs so much.

Comment: can you give an example of the changes its making?

Comment: What are you doing with the `HtmlDocument` afterwards? From what you've posted it seems that all you really need to do is do a `HTTP GET` to the website and save the content returned as a string on disk, with the HTML Agility Pack adding no value and just causing the modifications to the source you describe.

Comment: is it possible that the server you are requesting from is sending different documents based on the `UserAgent`?

Comment: Afterwards I want to search through DOM for every piece of text and replace it with numbers of each. But unfortunately even without doing anything the formatting changes (in this case formatting of the offer itself, which has all styles written in the HTML code).

And the user agent is taken from Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) will not necessarily write out the same HTML it reads.  If you check [the source](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.cs), you'll see that the writing (`WriteTo` method) pushes out parsed nodes.  If the original server sends invalid HTML, HAP will clean it up as part of its parsing.

If you need to save the original, use [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx), and load that saved file with HAP.

Comment: Great suggestion, I think that applies to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using HtmlAgilityPack a lot lately, but I have never experienced that issue.

What I do is the following:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var html = wc.DownloadString(@"http://www.example.com");
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//XPath/Query");
```

Does that change the html content?

Comment: This does not change the content. But check out the edit, I think I found the issue.